# Restart GlSurfaceView On Button Click

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

I am currently working on an Android application and I hope to restart the glSurfaceView on button click. Namely when a button is clicked, images should be read into the program again and all the textures should be reset. What should I do? Thank you.

Comment: I m working on similar problem.. hope this get answered soon

Comment: Usually you would restore Textures in the GLSurfaceView.Renderer.onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) call. So you could manually call this when a Button click occurs (bit of a hack).

Comment: It is not so Thread Friendly to forcefully call it from the UI Thread isn't it?

Comment: Thank you for your help. But I am wondering what should be used as the parameters of the method onSurfaceCreated?@JohnThompson

Comment: Hi, BLOB. Will this method cause some other problems? I am not sure whether this method is Thread Friendly. @BLOB

Comment: restart means, you want to clear the GLSurfaceview[ie.. we drawn lines etc.. you want to clear it..]..

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just want to reload the data and not recreate the textures after a user navigates back to your application.  In that case create a method in your renderer that is public say setResetFlag().  In this method you set a boolean variable reset.  In the onDrawFrame method, check to see if the flag is set, and reload your textures/reset your state if it is set (resetting its state back to the nominal non reset state).  This way you offload the work to the openGL thread and keep the UI nice and responsive.

Comment: Thank you for your help. But I hope to recreate the textures. I hope to restart the glSurfaceView. Now I use the method of onResume to achieve this goal. However, I am not sure whether there are any better methods.